# Carbon don't take PHP timezone when W3c is converted to DateTimeString

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

When ISO-8601 datetime is parsed with `parse()`, Carbon don't read PHP timezone when `toDateTimeString()` is used (for MySQL, for example). Check the next code:

```
$date_with_tz = '2018-09-04T19:12:34-04:00';
echo Carbon::parse($date_with_tz)->toW3cString().PHP_EOL;
echo Carbon::parse($date_with_tz)->toDateTimeString().PHP_EOL;
$date_with_tz = '2018-09-04T19:12:34-03:00';
echo Carbon::parse($date_with_tz)->toW3cString().PHP_EOL;
echo Carbon::parse($date_with_tz)->toDateTimeString().PHP_EOL;
```

*[php.date_timezone='America/Argentina/Mendoza'] (-03:00)*

Dump

```
// 2018-09-04T19:12:34-04:00
// 2018-09-04 19:12:34
// 2018-09-04T19:12:34-03:00
// 2018-09-04 19:12:34         <-- Wrong
```

Expected

```
// 2018-09-04T19:12:34-04:00
// 2018-09-04 19:12:34
// 2018-09-04T19:12:34-03:00
// 2018-09-04 20:12:34         <-- OK (expected)
```

Comment: "W3C datetime" isn't a thing, I think you mean [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: thanks... post updated :) I based it in the name of the Carbon method :P

Comment: @pablorsk, have you tried using Carbon methods steTimeZone or shiftTimeZone ?

Comment: I can do `Carbon::parse($date_with_tz)->setTimezone('UTC')->toDateTimeString()` but, how can configure this for Laravel? For example, on API, the user can be send datetime in different timezones...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you think date_default_timezone_set should do here but it's not going to change the timezone of a DateTime or Carbon instance, it would just be the default if one was not provided.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// -03:00 (provided via offset in date format)
$dateWithOffset = Carbon::parse('2018-09-04T19:12:34-03:00'); // -03:00

// -04:00 (provided via timezone parameter)
$dateWithTZ = Carbon::parse('2018-09-04T19:12:34', 'America/New_York');

// 00:00 (this is the only one affected by the default setting since no offset or timezone was provided)
$dateWithoutOffset = Carbon::parse('2018-09-04T19:12:34');
```

These 3 instances will output the same numbers if you were to use the format or toDateTimeString methods.  Neither will change the timezone when outputting.

If you want to output a UTC timestamp, use the setTimezone method to convert the timezone of the other instances before output.

```
$dateWithOffset->setTimezone('UTC')->toDateTimeString()
```

Comment: Yeap! you can do `Carbon::parse($date_with_tz)->setTimezone('UTC')->toDateTimeString()` and allways get a same UTC datetime. But, how can I set this for all laravel project?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?  Set what?  Write a helper function if need be but toDateTimeString doesn't do any conversion.